# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is randomly FALSE with OWIN cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-web-api, active-directory, owin

I have an ASP .NET MVC 5 application which also has Web API components however i dont think they are a factor here.

My problem is that randomly, after logon, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated (and Request.IsAuthenticated) is FALSE.

I am not getting any callback to my AuthenticationFailed callback and everything else seems normal.

What is the difference between, and which of these should I be using:

```
Request.IsAuthenticated
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated
```

Comment: It really depends on where you are accessing them. Due to MVC's/WebApi's pipeline using OWIN you can get different results. More info: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters
I don't know the details exactly, but this might be a good starting point

Comment: Are you accessing your WebApi using your cookies? If yes, there's no way you can authenticate your WebApi using cookies

Comment: This is a standard MVC application with Web API controllers bolted on later. The issue is occuring within the MVC at Home/Index. That action either returns a landing page if not authenticated or the home page otherwise. In the case where its failing the user logs in and is then dropped back to the landing page. At this point there is no Web API.

Comment: any luck on this one?

Comment: Nothing definitive. I have no solution other than to suspect it has something to do with Chrome and cookies/caching. Its an old thread and I have moved on from that particular application but from what i understand it doesnt happen anymore, possibly Chrome or possibly updates to owin components. Not sure sorry.

Comment: My issue is not random but it only manifests when using Chrome and goes away when I browse in incognito mode.